# Why is the distinction from "coordinative bond" useful at all?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, bond, coordination-compounds

There are 3 types of coordinative bonding, *complex formation at the electron donor*, *complex formation at the electron donor acceptor* and *complex formation at the electron acceptor*, so what is the difference between coordinative bonding and covalent and ionic bonding?

Holleman (the German "Bible" of Inorganic Chemistry in the 102nd edition) even writes that there is basically no difference, so why is there this concept at all?

[image]

In other sources I find the explanation that coordinative bonds only refer to those where the electron pair comes from a single atom (donor), but Hollemann (whom I normally trust a lot) even writes:

> Coordination bonds can formally originate half from Z and half from L.

The other two cases (whole of L or Z) agree with the well-known definition of coordinative bonds...

> ...in which the two electrons derive from the same atom.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinate%20covalent%20bond?oldformat=true

Comment: This can pretty easily become a bottomless pit. It's good you trust hw, it's a great book. Not for beginners though. The description of chemical bonding is a hot button topic. Essentially, there are two types: ideally covalent and ideally ionic. And there is a spectrum between. A coordinate bond often is more covalent than ionic. There are no clear lines and the ideal forms don't exist. The rest is a bit ideology and what's easiest to understand. There, I hope I didn't make your question worse...

Comment: @Martin-マーチン Something between covalent and ionic should rather be polar covalent, I have the diagram in mind which shows the "ionic character" depending on the electronegativity difference, but then I just don't know where the concept of "coordinative" bonding should find place.

Comment: Just a different label, a coordinate bond usually is polar covalent. That's true for almost all bonds though. It easily finds its place with bond formation. And with complexes and with ligands and back bonding and lots of other stuff. It's really descriptive for the chemical reaction happening. Think for example dissolution of a salt. Also: ionic character does not depend electronegativity. That's just a nice rule of thumb.

Comment: Heavyhearted I'll be closing this question. I think it steers in the right direction, but ultimately, I cannot be answered by fact. It'll always be a discussion and there will always be opposing sides. If I had an idea to remove this from the question, please trust me, I would have used it to keep it open. In its current form, it's too attractive to create opinionated answers.